# Trying to store and save a POST response to Display to UI

Tags: javascript, angular

So this is what my Apps Front end is Displaying to the User currently.

[image]

Code in component.ts :

```
importCsvFile() {
    this.coreService.importCsvFile(this.file, this.importCsvUrl).subscribe(
      (rollout: RolloutRecord) => {
        this.selectedRollout = rollout;
        this.notify.success("Success", "Successfully updated the MSS values");
        this.search(true);
        this.displayDialog = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.coreService.csvImportHandleError(error);
        this.displayDialog = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Code in the core.service.ts

```
csvImportHandleError(error){
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
      this.notify.error('Backend returned status code: ', error.message);
      // this.notify.error('Response body:', error.name);
    } else {
      //A client-side or network error occurred.
      this.notify.error('An error occurred:', error.statusText);
    }
  }
```

What I am attempting to display to the User is the reason:
[image]

Any help is appreciated this is my first time using angular or JS, I've spent hours today looking all over this site, and I cant figure out which approach to use.... and trying to avoid using interceptors if I can.... If anyone has a tutorial link that's also greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

[console.log(error) output]
[image]

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

Comment: Instead of `error.message` try `error.errors.reason` assuming that photo is what you get from logging the `error` object.

Comment: errors isn't recognized? am I missing an import? ------> import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

Comment: Do you just have to declare the type of `errors`? Like `(error.errors as any).reason`? If that doesn't work put `console.log(error)` and show us what the error looks like.

Comment: updated, hope that helps, thanks for the help once again, pulling my hair out over here..

Comment: So it's `error.error.errors.reason`.

Comment: god bless you..... that did it. thank you so much. Appreciate the WebDev console trick to identify that